# How to start the popup lightbox onLoad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a lightbox popup. I want it to pop up when the webpage loads and close it when they click the lightbox popup.  How can I do this?

Here is what I have so far but it doesn't work.

HTML FILE:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Lightbox 2</title>
<meta name="description" lang="en" content="testing" />
<meta name="author" content="Lokesh Dhakar">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="images/favicon.gif" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" 
    media="screen" />
<link 
    href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredoka+One|Open+Sans:400,700'
    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<body>
<a href="images/examples/image-1.jpg" rel="lightbox">
    <img src="images/examples/thumb-1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a href="images/examples/image-2.jpg" rel="lightbox" 
    title="Optional caption."><img src="images/examples/thumb-2.jpg" 
    alt="" /></a>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS FILE:

```
(function() {
  var $, Lightbox, LightboxOptions;

  $ = jQuery;

  LightboxOptions = (function() {

function LightboxOptions() {
  this.fileLoadingImage = 'images/loading.gif';
  this.fileCloseImage = 'images/close.png';
  this.resizeDuration = 700;
  this.fadeDuration = 500;
  this.labelImage = "Image";
  this.labelOf = "of";
}

return LightboxOptions;

  })();

  Lightbox = (function() {

function Lightbox(options) {
  this.options = options;
  this.album = [];
  this.currentImageIndex = void 0;
  this.init();
}

Lightbox.prototype.init = function() {
  this.enable();
  return this.build();
};

Lightbox.prototype.enable = function() {
  var _this = this;
  return $('body').on('click', 'a[rel^=lightbox], area[rel^=lightbox]', function(e) {
    _this.start($(e.currentTarget));
    return false;
  });
};

Lightbox.prototype.build = function() {
  var $lightbox,
    _this = this;
  $("<div>", {
    id: 'lightboxOverlay'
  }).after($('<div/>', {
    id: 'lightbox'
  }).append($('<div/>', {
    "class": 'lb-outerContainer'
  }).append($('<div/>', {
    "class": 'lb-container'
  }).append($('<img/>', {
    "class": 'lb-image'
  }), $('<div/>', {
    "class": 'lb-nav'
  }).append($('<a/>', {
    "class": 'lb-prev'
  }), $('<a/>', {
    "class": 'lb-next'
  })), $('<div/>', {
    "class": 'lb-loader'
  }).append($('<a/>', {
    "class": 'lb-cancel'
  }).append($('<img/>', {
    src: this.options.fileLoadingImage
  }))))), $('<div/>', {
    "class": 'lb-dataContainer'
  }).append($('<div/>', {
    "class": 'lb-data'
  }).append($('<div/>', {
    "class": 'lb-details'
  }).append($('<span/>', {
    "class": 'lb-caption'
  }), $('<span/>', {
    "class": 'lb-number'
  })), $('<div/>', {
    "class": 'lb-closeContainer'
  }).append($('<a/>', {
    "class": 'lb-close'
  }).append($('<img/>', {
    src: this.options.fileCloseImage
  }))))))).appendTo($('body'));
  $('#lightboxOverlay').hide().on('click', function(e) {
    _this.end();
    return false;
  });
  $lightbox = $('#lightbox');
  $lightbox.hide().on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).attr('id') === 'lightbox') _this.end();
    return false;
  });
  $lightbox.find('.lb-outerContainer').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).attr('id') === 'lightbox') _this.end();
    return false;
  });
  $lightbox.find('.lb-prev').on('click', function(e) {
    _this.changeImage(_this.currentImageIndex - 1);
    return false;
  });
  $lightbox.find('.lb-next').on('click', function(e) {
    _this.changeImage(_this.currentImageIndex + 1);
    return false;
  });
  $lightbox.find('.lb-loader, .lb-close').on('click', function(e) {
    _this.end();
    return false;
  });
};

Lightbox.prototype.start = function($link) {
  var $lightbox, $window, a, i, imageNumber, left, top, _len, _ref;
  $(window).on("resize", this.sizeOverlay);
  $('select, object, embed').css({
    visibility: "hidden"
  });
          $('#lightboxOverlay').width($(document).width()).height($(document).height()).fadeIn(this.options.fadeDuration);
  this.album = [];
  imageNumber = 0;
  if ($link.attr('rel') === 'lightbox') {
    this.album.push({
      link: $link.attr('href'),
      title: $link.attr('title')
    });
  } else {
    _ref = $($link.prop("tagName") + '[rel="' + $link.attr('rel') + '"]');
    for (i = 0, _len = _ref.length; i < _len; i++) {
      a = _ref[i];
      this.album.push({
        link: $(a).attr('href'),
        title: $(a).attr('title')
      });
      if ($(a).attr('href') === $link.attr('href')) imageNumber = i;
    }
  }
  $window = $(window);
  top = $window.scrollTop() + $window.height() / 10;
  left = $window.scrollLeft();
  $lightbox = $('#lightbox');
  $lightbox.css({
    top: top + 'px',
    left: left + 'px'
  }).fadeIn(this.options.fadeDuration);
  this.changeImage(imageNumber);
};

Lightbox.prototype.changeImage = function(imageNumber) {
  var $image, $lightbox, preloader,
    _this = this;
  this.disableKeyboardNav();
  $lightbox = $('#lightbox');
  $image = $lightbox.find('.lb-image');
  this.sizeOverlay();
  $('#lightboxOverlay').fadeIn(this.options.fadeDuration);
  $('.loader').fadeIn('slow');
  $lightbox.find('.lb-image, .lb-nav, .lb-prev, .lb-next, .lb-dataContainer, .lb-    numbers, .lb-caption').hide();
  $lightbox.find('.lb-outerContainer').addClass('animating');
  preloader = new Image;
  preloader.onload = function() {
    $image.attr('src', _this.album[imageNumber].link);
    $image.width = preloader.width;
    $image.height = preloader.height;
    return _this.sizeContainer(preloader.width, preloader.height);
  };
  preloader.src = this.album[imageNumber].link;
  this.currentImageIndex = imageNumber;
};

Lightbox.prototype.sizeOverlay = function() {
  return $('#lightboxOverlay').width($(document).width()).height($(document).height());
};

Lightbox.prototype.sizeContainer = function(imageWidth, imageHeight) {
  var $container, $lightbox, $outerContainer, containerBottomPadding,     containerLeftPadding, containerRightPadding, containerTopPadding, newHeight, newWidth, oldHeight, oldWidth,
    _this = this;
  $lightbox = $('#lightbox');
  $outerContainer = $lightbox.find('.lb-outerContainer');
  oldWidth = $outerContainer.outerWidth();
  oldHeight = $outerContainer.outerHeight();
  $container = $lightbox.find('.lb-container');
  containerTopPadding = parseInt($container.css('padding-top'), 10);
  containerRightPadding = parseInt($container.css('padding-right'), 10);
  containerBottomPadding = parseInt($container.css('padding-bottom'), 10);
  containerLeftPadding = parseInt($container.css('padding-left'), 10);
  newWidth = imageWidth + containerLeftPadding + containerRightPadding;
  newHeight = imageHeight + containerTopPadding + containerBottomPadding;
  if (newWidth !== oldWidth && newHeight !== oldHeight) {
    $outerContainer.animate({
      width: newWidth,
      height: newHeight
    }, this.options.resizeDuration, 'swing');
  } else if (newWidth !== oldWidth) {
    $outerContainer.animate({
      width: newWidth
    }, this.options.resizeDuration, 'swing');
  } else if (newHeight !== oldHeight) {
    $outerContainer.animate({
      height: newHeight
    }, this.options.resizeDuration, 'swing');
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    $lightbox.find('.lb-dataContainer').width(newWidth);
    $lightbox.find('.lb-prevLink').height(newHeight);
    $lightbox.find('.lb-nextLink').height(newHeight);
    _this.showImage();
  }, this.options.resizeDuration);
};

Lightbox.prototype.showImage = function() {
  var $lightbox;
  $lightbox = $('#lightbox');
  $lightbox.find('.lb-loader').hide();
  $lightbox.find('.lb-image').fadeIn('slow');
  this.updateNav();
  this.updateDetails();
  this.preloadNeighboringImages();
  this.enableKeyboardNav();
};

Lightbox.prototype.updateNav = function() {
  var $lightbox;
  $lightbox = $('#lightbox');
  $lightbox.find('.lb-nav').show();
  if (this.currentImageIndex > 0) $lightbox.find('.lb-prev').show();
  if (this.currentImageIndex < this.album.length - 1) {
    $lightbox.find('.lb-next').show();
  }
};

Lightbox.prototype.updateDetails = function() {
  var $lightbox,
    _this = this;
  $lightbox = $('#lightbox');
  if (typeof this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title !== 'undefined' &&     this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title !== "") {
    $lightbox.find('.lb-caption').html(this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title).fadeIn('fast');
  }
  if (this.album.length > 1) {
    $lightbox.find('.lb-number').html(this.options.labelImage + ' ' + (this.currentImageIndex + 1) + ' ' + this.options.labelOf + '  ' + this.album.length).fadeIn('fast');
  } else {
    $lightbox.find('.lb-number').hide();
  }
  $lightbox.find('.lb-outerContainer').removeClass('animating');
  $lightbox.find('.lb-dataContainer').fadeIn(this.resizeDuration, function() {
    return _this.sizeOverlay();
  });
};

Lightbox.prototype.preloadNeighboringImages = function() {
  var preloadNext, preloadPrev;
  if (this.album.length > this.currentImageIndex + 1) {
    preloadNext = new Image;
    preloadNext.src = this.album[this.currentImageIndex + 1].link;
  }
  if (this.currentImageIndex > 0) {
    preloadPrev = new Image;
    preloadPrev.src = this.album[this.currentImageIndex - 1].link;
  }
};

Lightbox.prototype.enableKeyboardNav = function() {
  $(document).on('keyup.keyboard', $.proxy(this.keyboardAction, this));
};

Lightbox.prototype.disableKeyboardNav = function() {
  $(document).off('.keyboard');
};

Lightbox.prototype.keyboardAction = function(event) {
  var KEYCODE_ESC, KEYCODE_LEFTARROW, KEYCODE_RIGHTARROW, key, keycode;
  KEYCODE_ESC = 27;
  KEYCODE_LEFTARROW = 37;
  KEYCODE_RIGHTARROW = 39;
  keycode = event.keyCode;
  key = String.fromCharCode(keycode).toLowerCase();
  if (keycode === KEYCODE_ESC || key.match(/x|o|c/)) {
    this.end();
  } else if (key === 'p' || keycode === KEYCODE_LEFTARROW) {
    if (this.currentImageIndex !== 0) {
      this.changeImage(this.currentImageIndex - 1);
    }
  } else if (key === 'n' || keycode === KEYCODE_RIGHTARROW) {
    if (this.currentImageIndex !== this.album.length - 1) {
      this.changeImage(this.currentImageIndex + 1);
    }
  }
};

Lightbox.prototype.end = function() {
  this.disableKeyboardNav();
  $(window).off("resize", this.sizeOverlay);
  $('#lightbox').fadeOut(this.options.fadeDuration);
  $('#lightboxOverlay').fadeOut(this.options.fadeDuration);
  return $('select, object, embed').css({
    visibility: "visible"
  });
};

return Lightbox;

  })();

  $(function() {
var lightbox, options;
options = new LightboxOptions;
return lightbox = new Lightbox(options);
  });

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if your using jquery you can just create the link element as per the instructions and then use the following:

e.g

HTML:

```
<a id ="ele_id" href="images/image-1.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="my caption">image #1</a>
```

JS:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#ele_id').trigger('click');
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you wanted you could use a cookie to check if it's hte users first time on the site and only run the light box if that is the case.

Using jquery cookie plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
$('document').ready(function(){
     if ($.cookie('has_visited') != TRUE){
        $('#ele_id').trigger('click');
        $.cookie('has_visited', TRUE, { expires: 1 }); //this will set the cookie to expire after one day but you could make it longer
    });
```

Comment: i have a problem, if your help that appreciated, i had use your javascript code, its working well, thanks, but i used this code for my home page, when enter homepage http://q8marketz.com  its working, but i don't want its working again when click home button next time,what i want that only one time working this function, how to do this.? any idea.?? thanks

Comment: Easiest way is probably to set a cookie when the user logs in. You could then check to see if the cookie has been set before running the .trigger('click'). If your not familiar with cookies check this out http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp, you might also want to check out this jqery cookie plugin https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie, this makes life a lot easier, especially if you use cookies a lot

Comment: Yes, i understand, can your write a simple example code here.? thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of how you could do this

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<Style>
#fade{
display: none;
position: fixed;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #000;
z-index:1001;
-moz-opacity: 0.7;
opacity:.70;
filter: alpha(opacity=70);
}
#light{
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 5%;
left: 45%;
width: 640px;
height: 453px;
margin-left: -250px;
margin-top: 100px;                 
background: #CCC;
z-index:1002;
overflow:visible;
}
</style>
<script>
window.document.onkeydown = function (e)
{
if (!e){
    e = event;
}
if (e.keyCode == 27){
    lightbox_close();
}
}
function lightbox_open(){
window.scrollTo(0,0);
document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';  
}
function lightbox_close(){
document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';
}
</script>
<head>
<body onload="lightbox_open()";>
<div class="light" onClick="lightbox_close();" id="light"><img src="your_img.jpg"></div>
<div id="fade" onClick="lightbox_close();"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you please add some comment on what you changed and why? This would greatly improve this answer.