# jquery change attribute declaration

Tags: jquery

using a CMS which is automatically adding ="" to an attribute I have on an  on page save - I am trying to hack a solution in jQuery to remove it... but cant seem to get it to work.

So...

I want the markup to be:

```
<a href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/123" title="Watch now" data-lity>Watch now</a>
```

But - on save in the CMS the page is saved as below:

```
<a href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/123" title="Watch now" data-lity="">Watch now</a>
```

So,  `data-lity` is being made `data-lity=""` and it messing up the jQuery lightbox function....

Is there a way - I can find all instances of `data-lity=""` post page load and revert them back to `data-lity`?

Comment: Here's a link for  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688271/how-to-start-the-popup-lightbox-onload

Comment: Are you sure that is the problem? Both notations will give the same result: https://jsfiddle.net/gsreyjdx/

Comment: I hacked the lity.js to add data-lity="" as a valid attribute to allow it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I hacked the lity.js to add data-lity="" as a valid attribute to allow it to work.

At very end of lity.

```
//$(document).on('click.lity', '[data-lity]', lity);
$(document).on('click.lity', '[data-lity]', '[data-lity=""]', lity);
```

This made it work.